# How can i match decimal value with comma and parenthesis in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match decimal place and comma using  regular expression .
Below is my input :

```
  Tst:      (2344.45)
    Tst:      53.00
    Tst:     2777,46.00

o/p should be 
    Tst: (2344.45)
    Tst: 53.00
    Tst: 2777,46.00
```

I need to remove the spaces after Tst.
To match comma and decimal place I have used below regex .

```
(?:\d+)((\d)*([\,\ ]\d)*)(\.\d+)?
```

Edit :
Updated regex to match brackets and comma .

```
\(*(?:\d+)((\d)*([\,\ ]\d)*)(\.\d+)?\)*
```

Any clue on this would be  helpful .I want to achieve this in java

Comment: is the whole purpose of this is removing the multiple spaces after `Tst:` or do you also need to match numbers for other purposes too?

Comment: No I need to match any number with or with out paranthasis .And even comma  and number with decimal value

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 capturing groups, first matching word characters followed by a colon in the first and the number part in the second group.

Match 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars between them, and replace those with a single space.

*Pattern*

```
(\w+:)\h+((?:\(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\)|\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?))
```

*Explanation*

- `(\w+:)` Capture **group 1**, Match 1+ word chars and `:`
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:` Non capture group
  - `\(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\)` Match the number part with `(` and `)`
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)` Match the number part without parenthesis
- `)` Close non capture group group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fAfC3i/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/vdlwbL)

*Replace with*

```
$1 $2
```

*Example code*

```
String regex = "(\\w+:)\\h+((?:\\(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*(?:\\.\\d+)?\\)|\\d+(?:,\\d+)*(?:\\.\\d+)?))";
String string = "Tst:      (2344.45)\n"
     + "Tst:      53.00\n"
     + "Tst:     2777,46.00";
String subst = "$1 $2";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
System.out.printlnmatcher.replaceAll(subst);
```

*Output*

```
Tst: (2344.45)
Tst: 53.00
Tst: 2777,46.00
```

---

If you want to match multiple `:` you could use a quantifier (Note to double escape the backslashes in Java)

```
(\w+:+)\h+((?:\(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\)|\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yagsM9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex:  `\s*(\w+):\s*(\(?)(\d[\d,]*(\.[\d]+)?)(\)?)`

If you ignore text then try with this only: `(\(?)(\d[\d,]*(\.[\d]+)?)(\)?)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqnIiq/13) here

Java code here:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\S+)\\s*(\\(?)(\\d[\\d,]*(\\.[\\d]+)?)(\\)?)");
        List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(
                "Tst:      (2344.45)",
                "        Tst:      53.00",
                "Tst:     2777,46.00",
                "Tst: 245"
        );
        inputs.forEach(in->{
            Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
            if (m.matches()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(1)+" "+m.group(2)+m.group(3)+m.group(5));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following regExp:

```
[\\d+,?\\d+]*[\\.\\d+]?
```

Now if you just want the number, this regexp will work. If however, you want to extract both text as well as the number, you can use group operator in Java:

```
(\\w+:)\\s+([\\d+,?\\d+]*[\\.\\d+]?)
```

Now you can get the `String` value using in `group(1)` and the number with decimal and comma using `group(2)`

Comment: `[\\d+,?\\d+]` is the same as e.g. `[+,?0-9]` and `[\\.\\d+]` is the same as e.g. `[+.0-9]`