# How to match the ending parenthesis using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have some pattern which i want to match using java regex .The pattern sometimes has brackets sometimes it does not have .
Example of pattern:

```
Test string:      (2555.45)
Test string:      50.00
Test string:     2345,46.00
```

I have wrote the below program but somehow it does not take the ending  parentheses when I tried to match.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
    String re = ".*Test string:\\s+([^\\\\d]+\\d[.,]\\d+).*";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);

     List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList( "Test string:      (2555.45)", "Test string:      50.00", "Test string:     2345,46.00", "Test string:     620.26","Test string:     37687.20" );
//for (String s : arr) {
//    System.out.println(s.matches(re));
//}

inputs.forEach(in->{
     Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
   if (m.matches()) {
       System.out.println(m.group(1));
   }


});  


    }
}
```

What I might be missing here.Any clue will be helpful

Comment: I have added an answer on your previous question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61495498/5424988 with an update matching multiple `:` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis (`(` and `)`), are special characters to the regular expression engine. To go around this, we *escape* them by adding an extra `\` in front. Due to how Java works, we need to escape that extra `\` again, so to match `(` and `)` in Java you would need to have `\\(` or `\\)`.

Since in your test case the parenthesis might or might not be there, I suggest you add a `?` operator. I also noticed (unless I am missing something) that you are expecting to match 2 `:` characters as opposed to one.

Comment: Sorty its only single : so you mean ".*Test string::\\s+\\([^\\\\d]+\\d[.,]\\d+\\).*"; will be sufficient

Comment: @Rajesh:Not sure I follow your comment, but it needs to be like so: `".*Test string::\\s+\\([^\\\\d]+\\d[.,]\\d+\\).*"`